# mysql_query on utf8_general_ci collation

Tags: mysql, utf-8, utf8-decode

I'm having some trouble with running a query on a database using utf8 encoding.
Everything works fine until I try a string with special characters.
I can't really make a lot of changes to the database since I'm adding some separate pages to an existing prestashop template.

This is my code (sorry, but some of it is in Romanian)

```
$acces_server=mysql_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass);
    if(!$acces_server) die ("Server-ul nu este disponibil momentan !");
    mysql_set_charset('utf8');
     echo mysql_client_encoding();

$acces_bd = mysql_select_db($db_name);
    if (!$acces_bd) die ("Ne pare rau, dar baza de date nu poate fi accesata momentan !");
mysql_query('SET NAMES utf8') or die(mysql_error());
mysql_query('SET CHARACTER SET utf8') or die(mysql_error());
mysql_query('SET COLLATION_CONNECTION="utf8_general_ci" ') or die(mysql_error());
```

If I try to make a query  like this I get 0 rows:

```
$experienta= $_GET['name'];
$rez=mysql_query("SELECT nume_cutie FROM rez_experiente WHERE nume = '".$experienta."'");
```

I've used echo to display the query and then typed it in phpMyAdmin and it worked .
Also  the head section has this line :

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

I really don't know what else to do  , all the solutions I've found so far don't seem to work. I have even tried using mysqli instead and the result was the same.
Please help me , and thank you for your time.

*Edit 
I tried using stmt->prepare with mysqli and that didn't work.
I've also tried doing this :

```
$experienta2=str_replace("?","%",utf8_decode($experienta));
        $rez=mysql_query("SELECT nume_cutie FROM rez_experiente WHERE nume LIKE '".$experienta2."'");
```

Wich turns this :

```
SELECT nume_cutie FROM rez_experiente WHERE nume LIKE '5th Avenue Beauty Center  - Răsfăţ'
```

Into this:

```
SELECT nume_cutie FROM rez_experiente WHERE nume LIKE '5th Avenue Beauty Center - R%sf%%'
```

And again the query works in phpMyAdmin but mysql_query() returns nothing
I switched to utf8_unicode_ci and nothing changed.

Comment: Are you familiar with the story of [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)?

Comment: Does it fail for any name or only when the name contains a non ascii character? Did you try the utf8_unicode_ci collation?

Comment: It only fails when non-Ascii characters are involved .

Answer (score 0):

After the database connection, run these queries:

```
SET character_set_client=utf8;
SET character_set_connection=utf8;
SET character_set_database=utf8;
SET character_set_results=utf8;
SET character_set_server=utf8;
```

Comment: Still nothing  . Should I add it to the list of previous queries or replace them? Because I tried both and the result is the same

Comment: You can leave you existing queries, that is fine. They shouldn't be necessary, though. Your tables might have the wrong encoding set then. Edit your question with the output of: `SHOW CREATE TABLE someTable;` on the MySQL CLI and `locale` on the Bash CLI.